# how to find the current div based on the scroll position without Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Can someone help me out with this. I found a solution for this in Jquery but we need the solution in plain Javascript or Angular. I guess i'm missing something.[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqJ5q/57/).

When the content on the right panel is scrolled the corresponding left panel should get highlighted. How can we identify the current div element during the scroll to make it active? and that too without using JQuery.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$element', function($scope, $window, $element) {
  var totalclasses = angular.element(document.querySelector(".section"));
  var offsets = document.getElementById('section3').getBoundingClientRect();

  angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
    angular.forEach(totalclasses, function(value, key) {
    });
  });
}]);
```

```css
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
}

#sections {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 400px;
}

.section {
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

#section5 {
  height: 1000px;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="navigation">
    <p id="msg">
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li class="section1">Section 1</li>
      <li class="section2">Section 2</li>
      <li id="section3">Section 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="sections">
    <div data-id="section1" class="section">
      I'm section 1
    </div>
    <div data-id="section2" class="section">
      I'm section 2
    </div>
    <div data-id="section3" class="section">
      I'm section 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a solution with plain Javascript ( hope it works for you )

check it below or in [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vqJ5q/58/)

it's pretty straight forward .

first condition in the IF -> if the document scrollTop value is bigger than the section offsetTop -> then it means the scroll position reached the top border of the section

second condition -> if the document scrollTop value is smaller than section offsetTop + section height it means that the scroll position is still on the section so keep the `active` class

if these 2 conditions are not met, then the scroll position is not on the section so remove the class active.

let me know if it helps

```js
window.onscroll = function() {

  var section = document.getElementsByClassName("section");



  var bScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
  for (var i = 0; i < section.length; i++) {


    var sHeight = section[i].offsetHeight;
    var offsets = section[i].offsetTop;

    if (bScroll > offsets && bScroll < offsets + sHeight) {
      section[i].className = "section active";
    } else {
      section[i].className = "section";
    }


  }



}
```

```css
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
}

#sections {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 400px;
}

.section {
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#section5 {
  height: 1000px;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <p id="msg">
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li class="section1">Section 1</li>
    <li class="section2">Section 2</li>
    <li id="section3">Section 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="sections">
  <div data-id="section1" class="section">
    I'm section 1
  </div>
  <div data-id="section2" class="section">
    I'm section 2
  </div>
  <div data-id="section3" class="section">
    I'm section 3
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Mihai. although I was looking for a different implementation your logic solved my issue. I needed something like this-[link](https://jsfiddle.net/vqJ5q/59/)

Comment: oh. sorry. i understood wrong. but good job adapting my code :) glad i could help. cheers ! :D